# AS clause in influx DB

Tags: mysql, sql, database, migration, influxdb

How to use AS clause in influxDB?

```
SELECT os_family AS OsName, os_Image AS PlatformIcon FROM statistics
```

When I run this query I got following error.

```
ERROR: syntax error, unexpected AS, expecting FROM SELECT os_family AS OsName, os_Image AS PlatformIcon FROM statistics ^^
```

How to use SQL like AS clause in influx DB?

Comment: It is working in MySql. But I am using InfluxDB (http://influxdb.com/)

Answer (score 1):

The `AS` clause in InfluxDB is meant to be used in two cases (described below). That said we can definitely add this as a new feature if this is a common use case. I don't know if that's necessary though, if you want to get back the columns as `OsName` then why did you name it `os_family` to begin with. We can discuss this further on the mailing list (you can find information about the mailing list among other means to reach us here http://influxdb.com/community/)

The two use cases are for joining multiple time series:

```
select * from foo as f inner join bar as b where f.somecolumn > 0`
```

and to alias aggregators:

```
select count(value) as c from foo where foo.value > 100
```